# How to find the smallest n for inequality involving factorial, $n! > 10^6 $, what is $n$?

Tags: contest-math, quadratics, factorial

How to find the smallest n for inequality involving factorial, $n! > 10^6 $, what is n?

I solved it using calculator, that is the answer is $n \approx   9$. How to solve this inequality?

> Smallest $n$ giving $n! > 10^6$ ?

Edit
inequality relation

Comment: Are you sure it's an equation, and not an *inequality* that you're being asked to solve? Because the solution here is not an integer, I doubt it can be solved by hand.

Comment: See [Inverse $\Gamma$ Function](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/12828/inverse-gamma-function)

Comment: You are familiar with [the equivalence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function) $n! = \Gamma(n+1)$, where $n$ need not be a whole number?

Comment: $n!$ is divisible by three for all $n\geq 3$.  $10^6$ is not divisible by three, therefore no such $n$ exists.

Comment: @pjs36 - its an inequality relation , my bad !

Comment: Wouldn't a simple inspection suffice? $9!=362,880<10^6$ and $10!=3,628,800>10^6$.

Answer (score 5):

$$
\begin{align*}
9!&=1\cdot2\cdot3\cdot4\cdot5\cdot6\cdot7\cdot8\cdot9\\
&=(2\cdot5)(3\cdot7)(4\cdot6)(8\cdot9)\\
&<10\cdot 30\cdot 30\cdot 80\\
&<8\cdot10^5\\
&<10^6.
\end{align*}
$$
and 
$$
\begin{align*}
10!&=1\cdot2\cdot3\cdot4\cdot5\cdot6\cdot7\cdot8\cdot9\cdot10\\
&=(2\cdot5)(3\cdot7)(4\cdot6)(8\cdot9)\cdot10\\
&>10\cdot 20\cdot 20\cdot 70\cdot 10\\
&=28\cdot10^5\\
&>2\cdot10^6\\
&>10^6.
\end{align*}
$$

Comment: Factorial fun.  :D

Comment: Nice answer. +1